# Evaluate function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate the function in t = 1 in Matlab.
How can I get an answer to the following code ?

```
result = dsolve('D2y-23*Dy+22*y=sin(t)','y(0)=0','Dy(0)=0');
disp(result);
disp(fnval(result, 1));
```

The first answer is: `exp(22*t)/10185 + (23*cos(t))/970 - exp(t)/42 + (21*sin(t))/970`.

But when I am trying to find the evaluation of the function in the point t =1, the progrem is throwing some exception. Maybe the 'fnval' function is not suitable for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/subs.html).

```
result = dsolve('D2y-23*Dy+22*y=sin(t)','y(0)=0','Dy(0)=0');
t = 1;
subs(result)

ans =   
  3.5198e+005
```

You could also do it using [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), which is similar to your initial approach:

```
eval(result)
```

after assigning a value to `t`.

You can evaluate the function for a number range, using eval together with [`vectorize`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/vectorize.html):

```
t = -0.1:0.01:0.1;
plot(t,eval(vectorize(result)))
```

This gives:

[image]